# Reading a csv file using C and then doing string manipulation

Tags: c, csv, command-line

First I open a CSV file (`Cars.csv`) using my C file `cars.c`. My CSV file would look like:

```
toyota, 100, 20, 150.50  
nissan, 200, 50, 100.75  
BMW,    400, 80, 323.00
```

The 1st column is names, 2nd column is stock, 3rd column is order, 4th column is price.

Then I have to do two works(I will call the program in the commandline with the work name and any other argument I need to pass):

1. List all the items in the CSV file while the commas cannot be a part of the output. I also have to print headers for each column. (./cars list)
2. I would send an argument when running the program from the command line. The argument would be one the name of the items in my csv file. Then I would have to subtract 1 from the stock and update the CSVfile. (./cars reduce nissan)

This is how I opened the CSV file.

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *in = fopen ("Cars.csv" ,"rt");

if (in == NULL) { 
  fclose (in); return 0; 
}
```

//I need to store the data from the CSV file in an array of pointers. I know how to do that, but Im having a problem in storing them without the commas and then doing what I need to do in part 1.

//This is the only code I could write for the 2nd part.

```
int p =0;
for(p =0; p<; p = p + 4) {


if(strcmp(argsv[2],save[p]) == 0) {  //save is the array of pointers where I 
   int r = int(save[p +1]);           //store the data from the csv file
   int s = r - 1;
   char str[15];
   sprintf(str, "%d", s);
   save[p +1] = str; // not sure if this line actually makes sense
}
}
```

Comment: It's much easier doing this kind of thing in python or perl

Comment: Yeah I know, but I need to know how to do it in C too, thats why im trying to figure this out

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possible solutions.

Here's one:

1. Read the lines into an array of pointers. Allocate array with `malloc` and reallocate as needed with `realloc`. Read lines with `fgets`.
2. For each line, use `strtok` to split the line, and do whatever you need with each field.

Another solution:

Use your favorite search engine to search for an existing CSV-reading library (there are many out there, which can handle very advanced CSV files).

Comment: I've been trying th first part for quite some time now, and this is what I kinda figured out. I think I can store them in the array of pointers but I cant really figure out how to print the files.

if(strcmp(argv[1], "list") == 0) {

        token = strtok(str,s);

int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i<) {
        while( token!= NULL) {

          printf("%-8s", token);

          token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }
}

Comment: If you could finish my code for the first part, it'll be really helpful for me! Thanks

Comment: We don't usually finish anyone code here. Try finishing it yourself (experiment!) and if you'll run at any problems, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Think how the data should be represented and define a structure.

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
  int stock; 
  int order;
  double price;
} car_type;
```

Open the file:  See OP's code

Find how many lines and allocate memory

```
char buf[100];
size_t n = 0;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) != NULL) n++;
rewind(in);

car_type *car = malloc(n * sizeof *car);
if (car == NULL) OutOfMemory();
```

Read the cars

```
for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) == NULL) Handle_UnexpectedEOF();
  char car_name[100];
  if (4 != sscanf(buf, "%s ,%d ,%d, %lf", car_name,
      &car[i].stock, &car[i].order, &car[i].price) Handle_FormatError();
  car[i].name = strdup(car_name);
}

// Use `car` ...
```

When done

```
fclose(in);
for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
  free(car[i].name);
}
free(car);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me quite a lot. But I have one last question, when Im reading the cars how do I print that data out without the commas?

Comment: `printf("%-8s %d", car[i].name, car[i].stock);` (based on your comment elsewhere) looks like a good place to start.